# Motivation for some exercises in Atiyah-Macdonald

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, localization

I was doing the exercises in Atiyah-Macdonald and arrived at Chapter 3. And I found that the exercises from 3.21 to the end of the chapter was so weird and complicated. It talked about homeomorphism between spectrum and introduced a strange concept called **fiber** which I was complete unaware about it. So did the next exercises talking about **presheaf of rings** and **constructible topology**. When I read the proofs of them, I simply felt I lost in them.

So what are the motivations for these concepts and what references should I consult to get a better understanding of these exercises?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you looked at Eisenbud's book on Commutative Algebra?

Comment: Yes I've read some materials in it, but it didn't explain concepts like sheaf or so...

Comment: maybe you should read Hartshorne's book:algebraic geometry.

Comment: (1) Perhaps you are meant to learn about these concepts by working through the exercises, which is a process that will help you increase your understanding? (2) What do you mean when you say "When I read the proofs of them", did you mean "When I wrote the proofs of them"? You will not learn very much if you read the online answers to exercises... (3) My very serious advice is to skip some of these exercises on your first study. Even if you intend to study commutative algebra or algebraic geometry, you don't need to start immediately with these technical things.

Comment: @Teitler Thanks, very helpful comment! I was just too hurry to finish working on the book, so I just look at the answers before having a seriously thinking on them.

Comment: @Sky I start to read Vakil's lecture notes now. To see if there are any improvement...